# Disable date detection in Tire's elasticsearch mapping

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

I'm indexing a document with a property `obj_properties`, which is a hash of property name -> property value. elasticsearch is inferring that some of the property values are dates, leading to the following error when it encounters a subsequent value for the same property that can't be parsed as a date.

`org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse date field <NON-DATE FIELD within obj_properties>`

So, I'd like to disable date detection for `obj_properties` and anything nested within it. Per

http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Date-Detection-not-always-wanted-tp1638890p1639415.html

(Note, I believe the linked post contains a typo -- the field should be `date_formats` rather than `date_format`, but I've tried both ways)

I've created the following mapping

```
mapping do
    indexes :name
    indexes :obj_properties, type: "object", date_formats: "none"
  end
```

but I continue to receive the same exception. The properties in `obj_properties` are not known ahead of time, so it's not possible to create an exhaustive mapping of types. Any ideas? Is disabling date detection the correct approach?

Answer (score 2):

You can turn off date detection for a particular `type` by specifying it in the mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "mytype" : {
         "date_detection" : 0
      }
   }
}
'
```

or for all types in an index by specifying it in the default mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/?pretty=1'  -d '
{
   "mappings" : {
      "_default_" : {
         "date_detection" : 0
      }
   }
}
'
```

Answer (score 1):

```rb
mapping(date_detection: false) do
  indexes :name
  indexes :obj_properties, type: "object"
end
```

then `curl 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/myindex/_mapping?pretty=1'` will include `date_detection = false` mentioned [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/root-object-type.html)

Although i believe this applies to the entire index - not a particular field